# Connecting from computer 1 to 2 to 3 via ssh not working

Tags: ssh

On computer **foo**, my `~/.ssh/config` has the following entry

```
Host bar
    User punkish
    Port 2222
    HostName bar.example.org
```

On computer **bar**, my `~/.ssh/config` has the following entry

```
Host baz qux
    User punkish
    Port 2200
    HostName %h.example.org
```

I am able to `ssh` from **foo**  to **bar** without any problem ever. Once I am in **bar** from **foo**, I am unable to reach anywhere from **bar**. I can't `ping` out, I can't `ssh`, nor `curl` nor `git`. Nothing. It is as if there is a firewall blocking me. The image below hopefully explains the problem.

[image: network]

Things to note:

1. I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4 on all machines (foo, bar, baz, qux)
2. **foo** → **bar** works, but **foo** → **bar** → *outside world* does not.
3. Once I am physically at **bar**, I am able to reach the other machines just fine. That is, **bar** → *outside world* works fine.
4. Nothing about the network where **bar** resides ever changes.
5. There is no firewall on **bar** (or, for that matter, on any computer involved in this scenario)
6. **bar** has a static IP 10.0.2.20, which is reserved by IANA for private intranets, and not routable to the Internet. **bar** and is behind a router with the static IP x1.x2.x3.x4. Port 80 and the `ssh` port on the router are mapped to corresponding ports on **bar**, so I can reach web sites on **bar** and can also `ssh` into **bar**.

Fwiw

```
[bar] ~ sudo ipfw list
65535 allow ip from any to any
```

The command below shows nothing happening on **port 2200**

```
[bar] ~$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

The most important thing to note — I am able to successfully `ssh` out when I am physically at **bar**. It is only when I `ssh` *into* **bar** that I am unable to go anywhere out from **bar**.

What could be wrong? How do I even begin to investigate this? Is there a command I can use to determine if my ports are blocked, and if so, by what?

Comment: And what happens when you try to access the network?

Comment: As mentioned above, I can `ssh` from **foo** into **bar**, but then from **bar** I am unable to reach anywhere outside. `curl`, `ping`, `ssh`, all of them just hang. No error, no response. I have to CTRL^C to break out.

Comment: More information needed. Routing table. Full ifconfig -a output. Show dns servers each host is using. All the configuration details you can show from the 10.0.2.1 device. Then, stop relying on ping for a definitive answer, it causes many unsafe assumptions. Instead, can you telnet to any of these hosts and their appropriate port. For example, when I telnet to one of my hosts on port 22, I at least see "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3" and you should see something similar from your ports 2200 and 2222. Still more questions, but this should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

If bar is FreeBSD (it sounds like from ipfw) then tag this with bsd.

I would first ping the router from bar. Second I would ping and traceroute baz.

But, more importantly, can you reach *any* server in this scenario? Is the network card / stack broken?

Comment: from #1 in my OP, I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4 on all machines. Yes, I can ping the router at 10.0.2.1 from **bar**. I *cannot* ping the router at 64.x.x.x from **bar**. From #2 and #3 in my OP, if I enter **bar** via `ssh` then I can't get out to any machine. However, I can reach anything I want as long as I am physically at **bar**. That means nothing is wrong with my hardware. A buddy says there might something funky with my routing tables. I don't know how to debug that.